# Specific regex not replacing backslashes properly

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to do this

```
"love{ }&\abbc+".gsub(/([-\|!\(\)\{\}\[\]\^"~\*\?:\\&\+])/, '\\\1')
```

to get this output

```
"love\{ \}&\\abbc\+"
```

but I'm getting

```
"love\\1 \\1\\1\abbc\\1"
```

in irb.
what am I doing wrong (ruby 1.8.7)?

Comment: Is your `\a` supposed to be a backslash followed by `a` or the `\a` escape sequence?

Comment: @muistooshort: post your answer (I could swear I tried five backslashes and it didn't work) :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: I'm too tired to explain why so many cursed backslashes are needed and I'm never happy with a simple "do this" answer without an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the block form maybe?

```
"love{ }&\abbc+".gsub(/([-\|!\(\)\{\}\[\]\^"~\*\?:\\&\+])/) { |m| "\\#{m}" }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"love{ }&\abbc+".gsub(/([-\|!\(\)\{\}\[\]\^"~\*\?:\\&\+])/, "\\\\\\1")
```

See http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/143645 for an explanation of why all the extra escaping is necessary.